# How to set service description that shown in task manager

Tags: android

My application starts a service that keep running in background. Service class "ConnSrv" is not descriptive enough for users. How can I set service name that shown in OS taskmanager?

Comment: Have you tried `android:label` in the `<service>` element in the manifest?

Comment: Oops i'm stupid. Thanks alot. I thought its somehow connected with startService or Intent parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:label` *generally* controls the display names of components:

- On an `<activity>`, it controls things like the caption associated with a launcher icon, or the default title in the action bar
- On a `<receiver>`, it controls things like the display name of an app widget in the device's roster of available app widgets
- On a `<service>`, it apparently covers how the service is named in the list of running services (I never tried this, which is why I started with a comment...)
- On an `<application>`, not only does it control things like the name in the installed apps list in Settings, but it provides the default for all `<activity>`, `<receiver>`, and `<service>` elements that do not override it

Comment: There is a "description" in the manifest for "service" tag, but I can't see where it's shown. Here are the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#desc . Can you please tell me where to see it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Ummmm... I have no idea. There used to be a dedicated list of running services in the Settings app, and it might show up there. Anything that wants to *can* show it, as [it appears to be available via `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ComponentInfo.html#descriptionRes). To be honest, I don't know if I have ever seen anyone set that attribute on a `<service>` element.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The "running services" screen from the developer options shows the description of the services. But I wonder if normal users can see it. And I also wonder if I saw this screen somewhere else and it got moved to developer options in the recent Android versions (Probably to avoid causing harm to apps).

Comment: @androiddeveloper: That definitely used to be part of the "Apps" area of Settings -- Android 4.x timeframe, perhaps.

Comment: That far in the past? Perhaps. I almost never used it, not even as a developer. Doesn't seem like it gives you essential operations. Only harmful ones.